# spring mvc mockito junit

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, mockito

I am new to spring mvc junit tests. we are using mockito to mock the objects.

For the below piece of code I am not able to mock. please help me to know where am going wrong.

in my controller class we have

```
SpringApplicationContext.getBean ("somevalidator");
```

inside getbean ()

```
public static <T> T  getBean (String beanName){
    return (T) application Context.getBean            (beanName);
}
```

please help me how to mock the above code.

Comment: You can't mock static methods with Mockito. Either change your design or add a library like PowerMock.

Comment: Thanks for reply Robby..can you pls suggest me with any other mocking API I can mock the above scenario?

Comment: Don't use that method, why aren't you simply using dependency injection that way you don't  need to solve this problem. Basically where you are wrong is the initial design of that class and the usage of the static lookup of a bean. Instead of mocking, you can mock the `ApplicationContext.getBean` call and inject that mock into that ugly utility class of yours or use a `StaticApplicationContext` for this test and register the beans you need to be looked up.